# How to design a database so each entry can store reference to other entries?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database in which every entry represents a user.
Now i wish that every user could have friends, IE, each entry will have a field 'friends' and it will have multiple items that represents other users.

I am not sure if thats even possible, and if not i would love to know how i can do this properly.

My databse is MySQL if that matters.

Thank you.

Comment: Use another table called `friends` to relate 2 users. If one person has multiple friends the table would have multiple rows or that user.

Comment: Im not sure i quite follow..
Do you mean create a table for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Use another table called `friends`

for instance

```
users table
-----------
id    name
1     tom
2     peter
3     jane
```

Now if you want user 1 being friends with 2 and 3 your table looks like this

```
friends table
-------------
user_id    friend_id
1          2
1          3
```

Comment: I see. this makes alot of sense :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To extend @juergend's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36679669/5830574) I would go with the following approach (I used the user names he already suggested):

```
create table users (
    id      int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name    varchar(20)
);

create table friends (
    user1 int not null references users(id),  
    user2 int not null references users(id)
);

insert into users (name) values ('tom'), ('peter'), ('jane');

select * from users;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | tom   |
|  2 | peter |
|  3 | jane  |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- make jane and peter friends:
insert into friends (user1, user2) values (
    (select id from users where name='jane'),
    (select id from users where name='peter')
);

select u1.name, u2.name 
  from users u1 
  join friends f on u1.id=f.user1
  join users u2 on f.user2=u2.id;     
+------+-------+
| name | name  |
+------+-------+
| jane | peter |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now it depends on whether you want your friendship be symmetric or not (i.e. Jane/Peter <=> Peter/Jane). If so, you would need two entries in the `friends` table.

Comment: This is a really nice approach and really suites my needs.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You must have create two saprate table to handle multiple friends entry like below..

Table 'user'
user_id
user_name
...

Table 'friends'
id
user_id_1
user_id_2
...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the id of every user(user name will work as id as long as all user names are unique) called the primary key

then define an other table called friends which will include the rows like

user name | friend name
user name | friend name

this type of structure is called a one to many relationship.

[tables picture illustrate parent child relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUvG.png)

```
users table         friends table       

id  username    row_id  user    friend
1   ali         1   ali khurram
2   khurram     2   ali tazeen
3   tazeen      3   ali babar
4   babar       4   khurram ali
                5   khurram babar
```